# UUID encoded as ascii not as utf-8

Tags: utf-8, ascii, encode, uuid

In almost all examples UUID is encoded to utf-8 for example.

"aa4aaa2c-c6ca-d5f5-b8b2-0b5c78ee2cb7".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

UUID is not ascii format? Why everyone encodes to utf-8?

Answer (score 2):

UUID is encoded as a 128-bit object (see [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)). Your example is the textual representation in hexadecimal of an UUID value.

There is no particular encoding required for UUID. I guess UTF-8 is used probably because it is the default encoding for various exchange formats such as for example JSON.

Comment: @heisenberg_ This begs the question of why you would want a byte representation of a text representation of UUID, rather than the bytes of the UUID themselves.

Comment: @TomBlodget to hash later.
byte[] hashedPassword = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "UUID is not ascii format?" UUID is a 128-bit number, and this is one (ambiguous) way to encode it into a string. Do you mean "why do people use UTF-8 when ASCII is equivalent?" Because it's good habit to use UTF-8 for most things unless you have a reason not to. When it's equivalent to ASCII, it's the same, so it doesn't matter. When it's not equivalent to ASCII, you usually wanted UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for reply!
My doubt is some languages as i could understand UUID can be just numbers letters and some other that fits in ascii, that means a russian character is a valid text representation in UUID...So in that case is just equivalent to ascii

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a russian character is a valid text representation in UUID." A UUID is just a number. Its canonical string form is defined in RFC 4122 (which is compatible with the official definition in ISO/IEC 9834-8:2004). The RFC lays out the exact characters that can be included, and their structure. There are no Russian characters in the list. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122  The reason I say this format is ambiguous is that it is case-insensitive for input, which means two different strings may be the same UUID.

Comment: Tks for reply. I could test, what i would like to say is:
Lets consider the following String, "teste"...think as bytes, string ok.

"teste" encoded in ascii will result: 0111010001100101011100110111010001100101

"teste" encoded in utf-8 will result: 0111010001100101011100110111010001100101 (Same thing)

"testeüüä" encoded in ascii will result: 
0111010001100101011100110111010001100101001111110011111100111111

"testeüüä" encoded in utf-8 will result: 
0111010001100101011100110111010001100101110000111011110011000011101111001100001110100100(different because of üä)

Comment: is the same thing of UUID,,,if i consider an uuid in hexadecimal and i have to encode does not matter if its ascii or utf-8 the result will be always the same.

Comment: Exactly, which is why you use UTF-8, since when in doubt, you should always use UTF-8.

Comment: @heisenberg_ "testeüüä" *cannot" be encoded in ASCII; you may be thinking of some other encoding such as Latin-1. This is a perfect example of why nearly everyone now uses UTF-8 for everything: it can handle *any* Unicode code points, yet it doesn't waste any space for the (very common) ASCII subset--such as UUIDs.